# Renamed Android Studio package, but changing package name in Manifest gives many errors

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I refactored/renamed the package under src/java and changed the package name in build.gradle. But when I try to change the package name in the Manifest file, I get many compile errors in source files. Thank you for your help.

Comment: your root folder (above src) doesnt matches with the new package name?

Comment: the new package name is org.researchstack.sampleapptest1, and the root folder name is sampleapptest1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the project in your IDE.

Move the physical files in yourprojectfolder>sampleapptest1 to yourprojectfolder>researchstack>sampleapptest1.

Reopen the project in your IDE.